# How do I delete rect object from screen once player collides with it?

Tags: python, pygame

in `draw()` function I am trying to delete rect object when player pos = enemy pos but "del" will not work. Any way to delete the enemy object completely? Is there a built in pygame function to delete objects that I don't know about?

```
# draw player
def draw():
    enemy = pygame.draw.rect(screen, enemy_color, (enemy_x, enemy_y, 25, 25))
    player = pygame.draw.rect(screen, player_color, (player_x, player_y, 25, 25))
    
    # if the player is over the enemy then delete the enemy
    if player_x == enemy_x and player_y == enemy_y:
        # this does not work
        del enemy
```

Comment: You cannot "delete" something" what is draw on a Surface. A Surface contains just a bunch pixel organized in rows and columns.

Comment: is there any way to delete a sprite? *If I change the players to sprites*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot "delete" something" what is draw on a Surface. A Surface contains just a bunch pixel organized in rows and columns. If you want to "delete" the rectangle, then you must not draw it.
Create to [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) and do the collision test before. For instance:

```py
def draw():

    enemy_rect = pygame.Rect(enemy_x, enemy_y, 25, 25)
    player_rect = pygame.Rect(player_x, player_y, 25, 25)

    if player_rect.colliderect(enemy_rect):
        # create new enemy
        # [...]
    else:
        enemy = pygame.draw.rect(screen, enemy_color, enemy_rect)
    
    player = pygame.draw.rect(screen, player_color, player_rect)
```

---

Anyway I recommend to use [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) objects organized in [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group). [`pygame.sprite.Sprite.kill`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite.kill) remove the Sprite from all Groups.

Comment: Thank you so much! I now have a random spawner and it now changes positions when the player collides with it!

Comment: Now when I collide with the enemy though it changes pos (randomly) which is perfect however when I un-collide with the enemy, the enemy goes back to the original pos it was in. Any fixes?

Comment: @Caleb You have to show more code. Note, the comment section is not intended to ask additional questions, which extend the original question. If you have a new issue and a new question, then please [Ask a public question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and give all contributors the possibility to help you and to answer your question.